# How to get list of azure storage account turn off azure defender by using rest api or java sdk

Tags: java, azure, rest, security, azure-storage

I need list of azure storage account that turn off azure defender by using rest api or java sdk.
I just found only way to check one by one account by using this api
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securitycenter/advancedthreatprotection/get

Do anyone know other way to get this list by use only one request or use sdk?
I can't found any property to determine azure defender status by using java sdk AzureResourceManager library (AzureResourceManager.storageAccounts()).

Comment: Is using Azure PowerShell an option?

Comment: @GauravMantri sorry but just rest api or java sdk. Thanks guy